# Filter list web part on site page for references to that site page

Tags: list, web-part, filter

I have a Site Pages library and a Glossary list.  In the Glossary list, I added a lookup column to the Site Pages library (allowing for multiple values).  I am essentially looking to "tag" pages with terms.

When I create a new page, I want to add a Glossary list web part--which filters items for those referencing the page being viewed.

The dynamic filter option doesn't seem to get me there since it is user driven.  I can achieve this by creating hardcoded views for each page in the Glossary list, but it seems like there should be another way to achieve this.

Any thoughts?  Thanks!